# insert date query in sql plus

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g, sql-insert

so i'm trying to insert date in sql plus but it keeps on giving errors
the query is:

```
INSERT INTO Employee (empno, fname, lname, jobtittle, bdate, address, sex, salary, Superemp, dno)
VALUES (1, 'Anam', 'Irfan', 'Nurse', '1995-04-29', 'house1234', 'F', 8000, 455, 123 );
```

if it is inserted like this the **error** is  'literal does not match string format'
if it is like 29-04-1995 pr 04-29-1995 or with '/' it says `not a valid month`

If I use the `TO_DATE` function it says `SYSTEM.EMPLOYEE_DNO_FK violated-parent key not found`

Comment: Well you know you need to specify the format (or use a proper date literal); so what constraints do you have on the table? The error should say which constraint has been violated. (The way you've written the question, you've hidden the constraint issue after irrelevant date problems you already know how to solve, which isn't helpful really).

Comment: it says SYSTEM.EMPLOYEE_DNO_FK violated-parent key not found .what does that have to do with the date

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the date.

Answer (score 1):

The date errors are sort of irrelevant; you know you can avoid those by specifying the format mask with `to_date('1995-04-29', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`, or you could also use a date literal with `DATE '1995-04-29'`.

The important error is the one you mentioned in a comment, `SYSTEM.EMPLOYEE_DNO_FK violated-parent key not found`. What that means, based on the constraint name, is that you do not have a row with ID `123` in the parent department table. Either create a department with that ID, or change the `dno` you are inserting into your employee table to one that already exists in your department table.

(As an aside, you should not be creating your own tables in the SYSTEM schema. Create your own schema and do all your work in that).

Comment: yes done that but now the same error is in another insert query which says system.dep_fk violated no parent key found
but the table does not have a foreign key

Comment: You can query all_constraints to see which table that constraint belongs to. Presumably the department table? We can't see your tables or constraints. Please stop using the system schema though.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you are entering the date in the month place please enter that month's short form and not the number.
Ex: 22-MAY-1994 and not 22-05-1994